# Second Jquery chosen not displays item list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have two instances of Jquery chosen on the same page. First one is working fine without any issue. Second chosen not displays item list. I couln'd find out the reason for it. This is the code I'm using:

**Front view:**
Chosen :

```
<select  style="width: 100%;" id="groupsOptions"
                                class="chosen-groupOptions" maxwidth="100px"></select>
<select id="vehicleStatusDevice"
                                        class="chosen-select" maxwidth="70px"></select>
```

**Back end**

```
$.post('functions.php',{'deviceList':1},function(data){

        var deviceList=JSON.parse(data);
        var listSize=deviceList.length;
    var elements='';
    for(var i=0; i< listSize; i++){
        var device=deviceList[i];
        var vehicleID = device['VehicleID'];
        var deviceID = device ['DeviceID'];     
        elements +='<option value="'+ deviceID +'">'+ vehicleID +'</option>';
    }
    $('#vehicleStatusDevice').html(elements);
        $('.chosen-select').chosen({search_contains:true});

        //}).done(function(){
        //console.log("success");
        //}).fail(function (){
        //console.log("fail");
    });

//first Chosen

$.post('functions.php',{'groupList':1},function(data){
        var groupList=JSON.parse(data);
        var listSize=groupList.length;
    var elementss='';
    elementss +='<option value="all">All</option>';
    for(var i=0;i<listSize; i++){       
        var group=groupList[i];
        var groupName= group['Name'];
        elementss +='<option value="'+groupName+'">'+groupName+'</option>';
    }
    $('#groupsOptions').html(elementss);
        $('.chosen-groupOptions').chosen({search_contains:true});
    }).done(function(){
        console.log("success");
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("fail");
    });
```

This is how it looks like [image: looks like,]

Any tips would be appriciated.

Comment: where is HTML and JS code for 2nd instance of chosen ?

Comment: @vijayP Both HTML and JS code are in the same folder. Data comes from functions.php page to this JS page correctly.But they are not adding to the chosen.

Comment: so i am assuming that you have two `<select>` tags with same `id="groupsOptions"`. In such case your HTML is not valid as you are duplicating the `id`. I will suggest you to remove `id="groupsOptions"` from your `<select>` tags and only work with `class`. So instead of  `$('#groupsOptions').html(elementss);`, do it like ` $('.chosen-groupOptions').html(elementss);`; i.e. accessing the DOM element by class and not by id.

Comment: @vijayP No I have two separate Id for each chosen select.Okay I will try with only using class.

Comment: OK, so can you please show HTML and JS for second one just similar to what you shown for `id="groupsOptions"`

Comment: @vijayP I added both chosen